# Norms of a linear operator

Tags: linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $T$ be a linear  operator on $n<\infty$ dimensional real vector space $V$. Fix a basis $B$ of $V$, and let $[a_{ij}]$ be the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. basis $B$. Define $\| T\|=\sup\{|a_{ij}| :1\leq i,j\leq n\}.$

**Q.** If we change the basis, how the value of $\|T\|$ changes?

---

Frankly, I don't have much ideas of analysis; I don't know how to tackle this problem. The only thing which I thought intuitively was that the value of $\|T\|$ can change by changing basis, since a matrix with arbitrarily large entries can be diagonalizabe with eigenvalies, say within $1$ and $-1$, so norm is small w.r.t. a change of basis. I am not getting direction to solve above question.

Comment: Is the basis required to be orthonormal? If not, one important change of basis involves simply scaling one of the basis vectors.

Comment: There is no condition on basis (orthonormal etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a useful fact that any two norms $\| \cdot \|_1, \| \cdot \|_2$ on a vector space $V$ are what's called *equivalent*, which means that there are constants $0 < A \leq B < \infty$ such that $A \| v \|_1 \leq \| v \|_2 \leq B \| v \|_1$ for all vectors $v \in V$. For a proof, consider the set $F = \{ v \in V : \| v \|_2 = 1 \}$, a compact set, and look at the map $f: F \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$ F(v) = \| v \|_1 / \| v \|_2 . $$
By the extreme value theorem, we know the set attains a positive minimum and finite maximum.

But a family of linear maps on a finite-dimensional vector space is itself a finite-dimensional vector space. So since changing the basis would still leave this a norm, we know we'd still have equivalence in the sense of norms.